# Debugging javascript buttons

Tags: javascript, django

I have 2 java script functions triggered by two separate buttons.  I am trying to run this from within a django template.   `Button 1` works, but `Button 2` does not.  I am trying to make button 2 work.   Any reason why button 2 doesn't work?    Or how to fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addMore()
    {
      alert("Click!");
    }
</script>

<script>
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        alert('click');
    });
</script>

<button onclick="addMore()">Button 1</button>
<input type="button" value="Button 2" id="add_more">
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have jQuery loaded? Also, is Button 2 within a form or by itself?

Comment: Button 2 doesn't exist when you try to attach a click handler to it.

Comment: One side note, you perhaps missed the `type` attribute for the second script block, although most major browsers will treat it as JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap the code in `$(document).ready()` method. ex,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#add_more').click(function() {
        alert('click');
    });
});
```

the functions inside `.ready()` method initializes when the whole document is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use the jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to ensure the document is loaded before the code is executed. Eg:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        alert('click');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wrap that in this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
        alert('click');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HF5Bd/

Answer (score 0):

1) your second script is loading before the DOM. You need to use `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
     alert('click');     
    });
 });
```

---

2) another option is to move

```
<script>
    $('#add_more').click(function() {
     alert('click');     
    }); 
</script>
```

below

```
<input type="button" value="Button 2" id="add_more">
```